# Can't catch thrown exception by reference in c++

Tags: c++, try-catch, pass-by-reference

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int a = 3;
  cout<<"Address of a = "<<&a<<endl;
  try{
    throw a;
  }catch(int& s){ 
    cout<<"Address of s = "<<&s<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

Address of a = 0x7ffeee1c9b38

Address of s = 0x7fbdc0405900

**Why are the addresses of a and s different??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have different adresses, because they are different objects. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw) about `throw` :

> ```
> throw expression
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 1. First, copy-initializes the exception object from expression
>
> [...]

The reason to catch by reference is not so much to avoid a copy, but to correctly catch exceptions that inherit from others. For an `int` it does not matter.

---

Just as a curiosity, this is how you can get a reference to `a` in the catch block:

```
#include <iostream> 

struct my_exception {
    int& x;
};

int main() {
    int a = 3;
    std::cout << "Address of a = " << &a << '\n';
    try {
        throw my_exception{a};
    } catch(my_exception& s) { 
        std::cout << "Address of s = " << &s.x << '\n';
    }
}
```

Possible output:

```
Address of a = 0x7ffd76b7c2d4
Address of s = 0x7ffd76b7c2d4
```

---

PS: Just in case you wonder, I changed more on your code, because [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), ["std::endl" vs "\n"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n), and because [`return 0` is redundant in `main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

Comment: How is return 0 redundant?

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly `main` returns `0` by default, you need not write it

Comment: o. I always thought that was an compiler specific implementation.

Comment: @RitobrotoGanguly https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function -> special properties 4)

Comment: With my compilers, `"\n"` is slightly better than `'\n'`, because the latter is packed into a `char[2]` of `{c, '\0'}` (where `c` is `'\n'` in this case) and then calls the `char const*` routine.  But that's just the compilers I use and is an implementation detail; and other compilers may do it different.  Probably optimizes well at `-O1` or better, anyway.

Comment: @Eljay thats interesting. I usually use `"\n"` simply because it is more convenient to type, this time I wanted to do it "right". Actually I don't care too much about performance for stdout, because it is slow anyhow